# word/phrase for items added to an active contract

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Background: A contract between Mr. X and company Y includes a list of tasks that the company needs to complete. In the middle of the project company Y discovers that a few more tasks are needed, that are not included in the original contract. I'm looking for the word that describes these tasks, and implies that they were deemed necessary after the contract was closed.

These are my options so far, and my reservations about them:

- Addition(al) - doesn't convey the nature of these tasks, too generic.
- Exception - essentially they are not any different from the original tasks, had they been included in the contract on time.
- Extra - they are not extra, rather part of the necessary work scope.

Searches for each of these in M-W didn't provide me with something that hit the spot.

Example sentence

> The Contract contains 10 tasks and 3 ___________ tasks.

Extra points if someone knows the construction industry term.

UPDATE: What I'm looking to describe is different from a Change Order or *modification* of existing tasks. It's something that wasn't considered in the original agreement. So far I feel amendment is the best option offered.

Comment: Perhaps [***concomitant***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/concomitant) (as a noun or adjective) might suit.

Comment: This is really a legal question, and thus outside the scope of this site. Any answer to it is bound to be jurisdiction-specific.

Comment: They are called *add-ons*.

Answer (score 3):

When you change a contract like that, it's called *modifying* or *amending* the contract. Each set of terms added together is called an *amendment*. (It's also sometimes called an *appendix*, *addendum*, or *rider*, but those can also be portions added before the original signing.) If the amendment specifies tasks to be done, I don't know a specific word for such tasks, but you can say "The Contract contains thirteen tasks, ten in the original contract and three in the amendment(s) thereto."